# Error: "undefined reference to `__cxa_get_exception_ptr'" when compiling Qt Creator project for Symbian

Tags: c++, qt-creator, symbian, linker-errors

When I compile the project for Windows, it builds and runs fine, but when I try to compile it for Symbian S60, I get this error:

```
undefined reference to `__cxa_get_exception_ptr'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/+qt-s60-developers/qt/qt-s60/commit/23b0026a0c9cf5f195bcf3b14fcc408ccd91f762):

> Catch by reference rather than by value
>
> Catching by value causes GCC to use the compiler support function
>   __cxa_get_exception_ptr.  This is not available in the compiler support libraries on Symbian OS prior to Symbian^3.  Catching by
>   reference avoids this problem.

So replacing

```
catch (QString error)
```

with

```
catch (QString &error)
```

fixes it.